# Getting a slider to respond to clicks anywhere along the bar

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm using Python 2.7 and wxPython 3.0 msw (classic). This is my code:

```
class MusicPlayer(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MusicPlayer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # it remains to be seen if my new design choices
        # have any negative effect on the application
        # in the end.
        self.setupTimer()
        self.media_ctrl = self.setupMediaPlayer()
        self.media_ctrl.Hide()

        self.master_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.slider_sizer = self.setupSlider() #this should return a sizer.
        self.button_sizer = self.setupButtons()
        self.music_info_sizer = self.setupMusicDataView()

        self.master_sizer.Add(self.music_info_sizer, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=7)
        self.master_sizer.Add(self.slider_sizer, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.master_sizer.Add(self.button_sizer, 0, wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizer(self.master_sizer)

        self.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_LOADED, self.OnPlay)
        pub.subscribe(self.OnLoad, 'files_loaded_topic')

    def setupSlider(self):
        # I wonder if I need to add self to this...
        self.seek_slider = wx.Slider(self, -1, 0, 1, 2)
        self.seek_slider.Bind(wx.EVT_SLIDER, self.OnSeek)

        sliderSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sliderSizer.Add(self.seek_slider, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=2)
        return sliderSizer

    def OnSeek(self, event):
        offset = self.seek_slider.GetValue()
        self.media_ctrl.Seek(offset)
```

It's basically the guts of this media player I'm messing around with. The problem here is with the slider that I've got (I've omitted most of the other code to keep it easy to read). I can click on the thumb and drag it around the bar to jump positions within the song as expected, but whenever I try to change slider position by clicking directly on the bar, nothing happens.

I've tried using different events, wx.EVT_SCROLL and wx.EVT_COMMAND_SCROLL but nothing seems to work.

It doesn't help that the demo app has a super simple example of the Slider that seems to have this functionality working out-of-the-box, no changes needed.

Is there any way to get this functionality working?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `event.Skip()` as your last line of `OnSeek`.  Otherwise you catch the `EVT_SLIDER` and don't let it progress up the chain, so `wx` won't be able to respond to it. See [this](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/Event.html#Event.Skip), for example.

Comment: If you remove the line `self.seek_slider.Bind(wx.EVT_SLIDER, self.OnSeek)`, does the problem still persist?